# KVM causes high CPU loaded when cache='none'

Tags: virtualization, cpu-usage, kvm-virtualization

I've followed instructions on http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_KVM.
Host is Debian Squeeze Kernel 3.2, QEMU 1.0, libvirt 0.9.12 (all from squeeze-backport). All 4 guests are Debian Squeeze Kernel 3.2, also.

So my settings in Guest XML are

```
<cpu model='host-passthrough'/>
<disk [...]/>
   <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
   <target [...] bus='virtio'/>
</disk>
<interface [...]>
   <model type='virtio'/>
</interface>
```

IO scheduler on guests is set to noop. On host I tried noop/deadline/cfq with no significant performance differences, for me. All guests storage is provided by LVM. When using `cache='none'` and all guests have no noteworthy load, the 15 minutes average CPU load on host goes up to 3-4. But when using `cache='writeback'` the hosts CPU loaded rises down to less than 1. Can anyone explain, why the suggested settings for LVM causes the higher load on host?

BTW: When running disk benchmarks, the option `none` results in higher IO performance than `writeback`.

Comment: Your disks are slow?

Comment: No, on host and guests there's an average write rate of 170-180MB/s. I've set now `io='native'` and the CPU load on host is lower than 1 for more than one hour now, I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, with additional option `io='native'` in disk section and IO scheduler `cfq` on host system, I'll get the best results for my system. IO rate is nearly the same for all values of option `io` in guest XML and for IO scheduler on host and guest, only `cache='unsafe'` gives significantly more performance. But only with `io='native'`, `noop` scheduler in guest and `cfq` scheduler on host I'll get lowest CPU load.

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding the "native" IO mode. In my case this was sufficient to reduce the load, even when keeping the default (deadline) scheduler on the host. I found a presentation from RedHat (http://www.slideshare.net/pradeepkumarsuvce/qemu-disk-io-which-performs-better-native-or-threads) comparing the two modes, and it seems like the "native" mode is better for most cases involving an HDD, while "threads" mode is better for some cases involving an SSD.